# Cannot Convert From Method Group to Func<int>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am planning to have a dictionary which has a command string and function. When the user enters the command string, the function will execute. However, a compiler error which I cannot seem to fix is preventing me from doing this. `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Func<int>'`

```
class Program
    {
        static Dictionary<string, Func<int>> SendCmdList = new Dictionary<string, Func<int>>();

        static void test(int index)
        {
            clients[index].SendPacket(new Packet { Cmd = 0x8 });
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SendCmdList.Add("!send", test);
```

I don't seem to understand what is causing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With `Action<int>`: `SendCmdList.Add("!send", (n)=> test(n)); SendCmdList["!send"](1);`. Otherwise `Func<int, [what Type test() returns]>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Func<int>` i.e [`Func<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=net-5.0) means that the method should have an `int` as return type while your defined method is void so you either use `Action<int>` i.e. [`Action<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-5.0) like:

```
static Dictionary<string, Action<int>> SendCmdList = new Dictionary<string, Action<int>>();
```

which means method that takes an `int` input or change your method return type to `int`

Comment: Got it. By the way, do I have to have a parameter to use Action, and a non-void function to use Func? Is it possible to use either with a function that has a void return type and no params?

Comment: `Action` and  `Func` both require a valid type other than `void`

Comment: for without input parameter you can either use `delegate` or look for some other work around if any